# Problema con Realm en Android

Tags: android, realm

Hace muy poco estoy programando y me surgio un problema con Realm, que pienso que es algo con RealmConfiguration. Antes que nada les muestro el codigo donde creo esta el fallo:

```html
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("default")
  .schemaVersion(1)
  .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
Stats object = realm.where(Stats.class).equalTo("id", "Stats").findFirst();

if (object == null){
  stats = new Stats("Stats");
  realm.copyToRealm(stats);
} else {
  stats = realm.where(Stats.class).equalTo("id", "Stats").findFirst();
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comprueba si existe el objeto, si no existe lo crea, si existe lo llama.
El problema es que al instalar y ejecutar la aplicacion todo funciona bien (Es decir mis metodos funcionan, se actualizan los datos, etc) en el primer inicio, al cerrar y volver a abrir (Segundo inicio) los cambios hechos en el primer inicio no se ven. Pero si hago cambios en este segundo inicio de la aplicacion, cierro y vuelvo a abrir si aparecen los cambios guardados al tercer inicio. Espero que se entienda, si no diganme e intento aclarar mas. Muchas gracias.

EDITO: He hecho debug y cuando se ejecuta la aplicacion **por primera vez** mi Realm recibe este codigo **@4870** y mi objeto @4938.
Todas las demas veces mi Realm recibe este codigo: **@4871**
Esta bastante claro que aqui es el problema, lo que no entiendo es porque pasa y como lo solucino

Comment: revertí y quité la solución de tu pregunta, ese no es el modo de usar la plataforma, si ya tienes la solución usa el espacio de abajo para publicarla y recibir puntuación por ello

Comment: Además explicando los pasos que tuviste que hacer para llegar a la respuesta.